# What's the difference between "table" and "directory" terminologies?

Tags: data-structures

Paging in the x86 architecture is multilevel. There is a page **directory** which contains pointers, each one to a page **table**. The concept of directory also appears in **directory**-based cache coherence mechanisms, but there are no tables there.

I was wondering what's the difference between a "table" and a "directory". Do they mean the same but there are two names for the concept? Thanks.

Comment: Thanks @templatetypedef for your edit. However, this question is about none of the topics I reference. I'm asking about the proper meaning of "table" and "directory" and how they differ, not about the examples I put.

Comment: Gotcha, edit rolled back. Sorry about that!

Comment: It would be good to include a reference to where these terms are used.